# jQuery remove() not actually removing form fields in a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is driving me a little bonkers,

I have a form with a set of dynamic divs, each filled with several form fields. The user can remove one of these divs and when doing so I call jQuerys remove method on the container.

I see in firebug that the container is destroyed and removed from the DOM. However, when I  view the source of the page it is still there.

When I post the form, the fields which should have been removed are still being posted!

I suppose I could manually change the name of the form fields as a "hack", but am I missing something here?

Here's an example

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
    $(".remove").live("click", function(){
       $(this).parents(".container").remove();
   });
});
</script>


<form>

<div class="container">
    <input type="text" name="name_1">
    <a href="" class="remove">Remove</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <input type="text" name="name_2">
    <a href="" class="remove">Remove</a>
</div>

<input type="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: _"when I view the source of the page it is still there."_ Page Source doesn't demonstrate the current state of the DOM, that's why there is a  plugin called _firebug_.

Comment: as of jQuery 1.7 `.live()` is depreciated. You should use `.on()` instead with the latest version of jQuery

Comment: I'm downvoting this because the code above actually works. I can't see where those answers below came from. I may suggest the OP to actually provide an example code that resembles the problem he is having

Comment: you need to re-phrase this question. It seems your issue is that the form is sending the values you tried to remove, not that the form fields aren't being removed.

Comment: I'm having this problem with Rails, except it's not when I view source, which I'm aware does not reflect the DOM. Rather, I call remove() on a div and it disappears in the Chrome debug console, but <input> tags within that div remain! Everything else vanishes. I see nothing in the jQuery documentation that addresses this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$(this).parents(".container").remove();
```

To:

```
$(this).closest('form').find(".container").remove();
```

It looks like this is what you meant to do.

Comment: That actually removes all the divs with that class within the form.

Comment: @JasonWells. I understood this is what you meant, or else why would you use `parents`...? your question is vague.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I shouldn't be using parents. I want to remove the div the user clicks remove within.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/zBd24/

`return false;` in your event handler so the click on the link with empty href's aren't reloading the current page.

**edit:** code from the fiddle:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $(".remove").live("click", function(){
       $(this).parents("div.container").eq(0).remove();
        return false;
   });
});​
```

Comment: Just to clarify, it is removing from the DOM, I see that in firebug, and the behavior on the page is entirely fine as well. It's when I post the form, I am still receiving the previous values which were there when the page loaded.

Comment: still think it might because you're using the anchor tags without any href, which loads the same source on click.

Comment: Sorry that was my code example, in my actual real source the href="" is there.